# Cross reference table data in SQL

Tags: mysql

I've got a `bookings` and `contacts` table. I need to get all the email addresses that are found in the bookings table, but not in the contacts table. Is this possible in SQL?

There are like 160k rows for bookings, and 711k contacts so can't really be making arrays as it'll time out. Copy and pasting is also too difficult because of the size. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I would try a basic left join on emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your table structure is like, but this may apply to you:

```
SELECT email 
FROM bookings a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  email
    FROM    contacts b
    WHERE   a.email = b.email
)
```

This will select all the email addresses from the bookings table where that email is not found inside the contacts table.

Comment: Your suggested result is what I want, but this crashed the database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as this works for me. Are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: The database/server actually conveniently crashed at the same time as running this query for different reasons. This worked. Thanks (:

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check can return the expected result:

```
SELECT B.EmailAddress
FROM Bookings B
LEFT JOIN Contacts C ON C.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress
WHERE C.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN to find a record which is in your left table but not in your right table -

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.email_address
FROM Bookings AS b
LEFT JOIN Contacts AS c ON (c.email_address = b.email_address)
WHERE c.email_address IS NULL;
```

So for each email address in Bookings you match a search in the Contacts table
But then in the `WHERE` clause you discard the records for a bookings email address which is not in contacts.

The `DISTINCT` keyword will give you the unique email address.

Note: comparing email_address is not very efficient. If you could provide the structure of your tables, there might be a better solution.

Comment: I have the contacts table which has the field 'contact_email', and the bookings table, which has the field 'email'. There are roughly 711,000 contacts, and 160,000 in the bookings table.